# How do I reduce this code to one line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm very new to javascript, node.js and express.  My question is, how do I refactor the following code to make it one line inside the function?

```
exports.about = function(req, res){
 var mytime = new Date();
 res.render('about', {title: 'about page', time: mytime.toLocaleDateString() });
};
```

In other words, is there a way I can compress the var mytime = new Date(); and time: mytime.toLocalDateString() into one statement?

Comment: The best possible here: `new Date().toLocaleDateString()`.

Comment: Size is not important - readability is. This is a mind-set you want to get rid of as quickly as possible - trust me.

Comment: You can use `exports.about = function(req, res) { var mytime = new Date(); res.render('about', {title: 'about page', time: mytime.toLocaleDateString() }); };` but that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: VisioN had that answer I was looking for here.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Frits' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13994677/157247): You can, but is there really any need? It's nice and readable the way you've done it.

But if you really, really want to, this is how:

```
exports.about = function(req, res){
 res.render('about', {title: 'about page', time: new Date().toLocaleDateString() });
};
```

It looks a bit odd, but the `new Date()` part takes precedence, so you don't even needs parens around it (e.g., you don't need `time: (new Date()).toLocaleDateString()`). You could have them if you want, but they're not necessary.

Answer (score 10):

You don't. Readability over brevity. Let the machine do the minifying.

---

You could write `mytime.toLocaleDateString()` as `(new Date()).toLocaleDateString()`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

My prefered styling:

```
exports.about = function(req, res){
  var mytime = new Date();
  res.render('about', {
    title: 'about page',
    time: mytime.toLocaleDateString()
  });
};
```

Comment: ok, I get that, and I would probably leave it the way it is.  But is it not actually possible, or just not recommended?

Comment: No need in extra brackets.

Comment: Yes, _I_ need the brackets ;) `new` is probably not needed either.

Comment: @jstevens13 "impossible" is a thing that bad programmers say. Nothing is impossible, it's just a dumb thing to do so.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen `new` is vital here.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: *"Yes, **I** need the brackets"* LOL! Well put.

Answer (score 1):

ONE LINE

```
exports.about = function(req, res){ res.render('about', {title: 'about page', time: new Date().toLocaleDateString() }); };
```

This quite dumb though. There's nothing wrong with your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Making this piece of code any shorter won't make it any better. I'd personally make it a little larger, like so:

```
exports.about = function (req, res) {
    var mytime = new Date();
    res.render('about', {
        title: 'about page',
        time: mytime.toLocaleDateString()
    });
};
```

- I added a space after `function` since that's what JSLint wants.
- I added a space before the `{` because that makes it more readable.
- I placed all the object properties on different lines so I don't have to scroll horizontally all day (plus now I can add comments at the end of each property, yay!).
- Finally I replaced the spaces-indentation with tabs because that makes everything align perfectly while only requiring one key-press to remove or go over them (if your caret is at the beginning of the line 4 spaces would require 4 keypresses to move to your code, while a single tab requires just one keypress).

Answer (score 0):

You could do,

```
exports.about = function(req, res){
  res.render('about', {title: 'about page', time: new Date().toLocaleDateString() });
};
```

But that's about it. I do agree with Frits van Campen.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that it is better style to remove the mytime var because you are merely getting the current system time, and new Date() makes the intent perfectly clear.

```
exports.about = function (req, res) {
    res.render('about', {
        title: 'about page',
        time: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
    });
};
```